# How Can I stop the users from accessing ODBC?

Tags: mysql, odbc, ms-access-2013

I have a mysql backend and a ms access 2013 frontend, I configured a odbc connection at system level so it´s available to all users in the computer. But Now I realized that you can easily just open a new database and pull all my tables from that odbc connection and see the credentials.

I´ve already try with user level odbc, the database simply doesn´t log.

How can I stop the users from being able to do such a thing?

Comment: You really cannot stop users from doing that. Sorry to break it yo you, but ms access is not the platform for developing really secure applications. The best thing you can do is to use vba to dynamically create the connection and protect your vba project with a password.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a DSN-less connection plus connection caching.

Both are explained in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23430539/3820271

Then distribute your frontend as accde, so the source code isn't available.

Comment: I´ve been out for a while but, thanks for your reply I'll check it as soon as I can.

Comment: Thank you, for this answer I took the time now that I came back. It works perfectly. Thanks a lot!